# Speckles max intensity paradox

Tags: thermodynamics, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, laser

Wikipedia says ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speckle_pattern)) that in the limit of many interfering waves the distribution of intensities (which go as the square of the vector's length) becomes exponential
$${\textstyle P(I)={\frac {1}{\langle I\rangle }}\exp \left(-\frac{I}{\langle I\rangle}\right)},$$ 
where $\langle I\rangle $ is the mean intensity.

Allegedly, at the locations where the intensity is much higher than the average intensity, it seems that brightness / etendue is not conserved and the max limit of concentration is breached.

Which of the following statements is correct?

1. My analysis is wrong
2. There is no limit for concentration of coherent light
3. All of the above

Comment: Where have you heard that there's a maximum limit of concentration?

Comment: I heard it somewhere in the Israeli dessert,
But you can read about it also in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue#Maximum_concentration